# Laravel Eloquent with Oracle: add PL/SQL function as column to the Model

Tags: php, oracle, laravel, plsql, eloquent

In Oracle SQL, you can incorporate PL/SQL columns into your queries, by write the following SQL:

```
SELECT order_no, line_no, part_no, Parts_PKG.Get_Part_Desc(part_no) part_desc
FROM   order_line
```

What I would like to do is model this SQL statement in an Eloquent Model. When I extend an Eloquent Model based on the `order_line` table, the Model is not inherently aware of the `part_desc` column.  But I would like the Model to treat the column as a read-only field.

What is the correct way of doing this in Eloquent?

Comment: This is only possible with the case of ORACLE Functions only. Hope Parts_PKG.Get_Part_Desc this is a Oracle Function.

Comment: @AvrajitRoy Yes, of course it's an Oracle function.  It's a pre-existing function of my underlying application.  The question is how do I reference this function in Laravel/Eloquent?